# how to change textfield "line thing"?

Tags: flutter, textfield

[image]

how can ı change this blue thing color to Colors.amber.

this is my InputDecoration

```
InputDecoration(
        hintText: hintText,
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        focusColor: Colors.amber,
        hoverColor: Colors.amber,
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.amber),
        ),
        enabledBorder:
            UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cursorColor` property:

```dart
TextField(
  cursorColor: Colors.amber,
  // ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will change the cursor color for every widgets in your app.

```
ThemeData _defaultDarkTheme = ThemeData.dark();
ThemeData _darkTheme = initializeDefaultLineHeight(ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    useTextSelectionTheme: true,
    textSelectionTheme: _defaultDarkTheme.textSelectionTheme.copyWith(
        cursorColor: Colors.amber),
```

But you can explicitly declare the cursor color parameter to any TextField like below:

```
  cursorColor: Colors.amber,
```